# linq: projecting two sequences to third result sequence

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 sequences:

```
l1 = { "a1", "a2"}

l2 = { "b1", "b2"}
```

I want to return a third sequence:

```
l3 = { new A {a = "a1", b = "b1"}, new A {a = "a2", b = "b2"}}}
```

How can I use linq to do so?

Comment: Do you have something to show or just expect us to write the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the zip operation from functional programming, which takes corresponding elements from two sequences and builds a third sequence containing the matching pairs.  In C#, this is implemented using [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).  You can get the specific result you are looking for with

```
Enumerable.Zip(l1, l2, (elem1, elem2) => new A {a = elem1, b = elem2});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `Zip` API

```
var l3 = l1.Zip(l2, (left, right) => new A { a = left, b = right });
```

Note: This wasn't added to the .Net Framework until 4.0.  It's fairly easy to code up a 3.5 version though if that's what you're using.

Comment: It is in fact very easy to code up, but if you are lazy, I put the source code up here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a class A and both sequences have the same number of elements in the same order:

```
var l1 = new [] { "a1", "a2"};
var l2 = new [] { "b1", "b2"};

var l3 = l1.Zip(l2, (x,y) => new { A { a = x, b = y });
```